# Calling windows exe from python - pass data to memory instead of file

Tags: python, windows, cmd, gpsbabel

*This one is a long shot*, but...

I'm running a python code that calls [gpsbabel.exe](https://www.gpsbabel.org/) using [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

<sub>(there is a [python-gpsbabel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gpsbabel) package available, but it doesn't seem to be maintained and doesn't work out of the box).</sub>

A working sample code looks like this, where my USB device is connection to serial COM5:

```
from subprocess import check_output
comport = 5
filename = 'test.gpx'
gps_command = 'gpsbabel -w -t -i mtk -f COM'+str(comport)+' -o gpx -F '+filename
print check_output(gps_command, shell=True)
```

The standalone gpsbabel command would look like this

```
gpsbabel -w -t -i mtk -f COM5 -o gpx -F test.gpx
```

Both codes would create a file `test.gpx` in the working directory.

---

Here's my *long-shot* idea - instead of gpsbabel.exe writing to a file, I'd like to write the contents of `test.gpx` to memory or cache or something virtual, which can be accessed by python. This is mainly for performance reasons, so that I don't need to take the time to write a file and then re-read it.

**Is it possible with Windows batch, to replace a file on the disk with a virtual in-memory object?**

Because of drivers, I'm developing on Windows - but I would be open to ideas that work on other OSes, too.

---

If this isn't possible, next steps would be:

- to compile gpsbabel myself ([not so easy](https://www.gpsbabel.org/tips/Windows_build.html))
- use another tool instead of gpsbabel (nothing found so far)
- look into hijacking python-gpsbabel (although it seems just a wrapper for what I am already doing)

Comment: If i/o performance is causing a problem a 3rd party tool like imDisk can create a volatile ram drive (an in-memory virtual drive accessible via paths).

Comment: @AlexK. Great resource (I found a guide [here](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=356046)). You should consider posting as answer so I can accept.

Comment: All files are automatically cached on Windows. When you write the file the data is kept in memory for as long as that memory isn't needed for something else. Forcing it be kept in memory by using something like a RAM disk may significantly hurt performance because Windows may be forced to remove something else from memory to make room, like your Python program and its data.